# Stream 16 bit PCM to Wowza via Android Device

Tags: android, audio-streaming, wowza

I have an android device that is reading a 16 bit PCM audio stream from an external bluetooth device. I've been able to write that data to an AudioTrack and play it on the Android device, so I know that the stream works. What I'd like to do is send this stream to a Wowza server, so that I can then access the live stream through a web app.

I've been able to successfully send other streams to Wowza using the [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) library, but as far as I can tell, this library only sends streams that come from the device's camera and mic.

I've tried opening a socket and sending out each packet that I read, but I have no idea if this is the right approach or not. Does anyone have a good suggesting for implementing this?